# Find two previous articles

Tags: cakephp

I need to find two previous articles. Lets say, I got one article from database:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Pressroom] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 44
                    [created] => 2013-04-17 07:38:20
                    [date] => 2013-04-17
                    [modified] => 2013-04-23 07:58:25
                )

        )
```

And I need also find two previos records (Lets say with id 43 and 42). Any sugestions? I totaly got no idea.

I tried to use this code in my model:

```
$this->find('all',
            array(
                'order' => array(
                    'Pressroom.date' => 'DESC',
                    'Pressroom.created' => 'DESC'
                ),
                'limit' => 2,
                'conditions' => array('Pressroom.date <' => $data['Pressroom']['date'])));
```

But it finds two records with id 1 and 2, instead of 43 and 42

Comment: Try to be more clear with your question. You have that article an you want two previous ones; the immediate previous or any other before that? Limited by date? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question's a bit unclear, but would something like this work?

```
$articles = $this->Pressroom->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('id <=' => 44),
    'order' => array('id' => 'desc'),
    'limit' => 3
));
```